# How to use static library (windows phone 8)

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I cannot get static library linked against .exe application in MSVC-2013 for Windows Phone 8.0.

What I did:

1. File->New->Project->DirectX App (Windows Phone 8.0) -> Name it "MyApp".

   This template creates nice application that compiles and run without problems.
2. Right click on solution->Add->New Project->Static Library (Windows Phone 8.0). Let's call it "MyLib".
3. Right click on MyApp -> Build Dependencies -> Project Dependencies -> Make it dependent on MyLib.

   Still compiles and runs.
4. Go to MyLib.h and declare `int my_function(int x)`.
5. Go to MyLib.cpp and define `int my_function(int x) {return 0;}`.
6. `#include "MyLib.h"` in MyApp's CubeRenderer.cpp.
7. Add `int y = my_function(6);` in `CubeRenderer::CubeRenderer()` in CubeRenderer.cpp.

This produces linker error.

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl my_function(int)" (?my_function@@YAHH@Z)
```

MyApp depends on MyLib, so I do not need to set in `Linker->Input->Addidtional Dependencies`. Anyway, I have tried it and still get the error.

I have searched for `?my_function@@YAHH@Z` in MyLib.lib - and found it 5 times there.

Maybe I cannot use template named `Static Library (Windows Phone 8.0)` and should use `DLL (Windows Phone 8.0)` or `Windows Runtime Component (Windows Phone 8.0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a Project to Project reference to make this build. You can add this by right clicking the project Add->References and click Add New Reference and add MyLib to MyApp as a project to project reference.